# How to access browser's TLS certificate verification status inside the page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, certificate, x509certificate

How to access TLS certificate verification status from the browser (Chrome based, Brave, Edge and other types) inside the page using JavaScript?

I want to display status using HTML/CSS/JavaScript inside the rendered page that the server's cerficate is valid or invalid, trying to take this information from the browser.

[image]

Comment: Certificate is not part of DOM. You may need to interact with available browser API.

Comment: @Crypt32 I'm not sure there is such an API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API